# Commutative diagrams for lift

Tags: commutative-diagrams

how can i draw following diagram in latex ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Please show us the code.

Answer (score 3):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
&Z\ar[d, "g"]\\
X\ar[r, "f"]\ar[ru, "h"]&Y
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]